# MVC 5 Table-Per-Hierarchy Controller

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a class that represents list items in all the drop-down lists in my MVC application:

```
public abstract class ReferenceItem
{
    public ReferenceItem()
    {
        Active = true;
        DisplayOrder = 999;
    }

    public Int64 ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerType : ReferenceItem
{
    public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}

public class OrderType : ReferenceItem
{
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

This all works fine.  A single table is created, and each reference item is tagged by a discriminator column.  I'm calling the ReferenceItem views, as they will accept any type of ReferenceItem.  The problem is that I am having to create a separate, nearly identical controller for each type of ReferenceItem, so that the correct subset of data is passed to the views.

Could someone suggest or direct me to a resource that describes a clean way of using one controller and one set of views to accommodate a simple table-per-hierarchy scenario?  I considered a custom route of controller/type/action/id, but, being fairly new to web development, I was hoping to get some informed insight, first.

Thanks.

As requested, here are the Index and Details action methods of the "nearly identical controllers" as they are currently written.  The other action methods follow a similar approach of being tailored to the type.  I would like to find a way to write one controller that would manage any type of ReferenceItem.

```
    // Customer Types
    public class CustomerTypesController : Controller
    {
        private Context db = new Context();
        private string DisplayName = "Customer Type";
        private string DisplayNamePlural = "Customer Types";

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Header = DisplayNamePlural;
            return View("~/Views/ReferenceItems/Index.cshtml"
                , db.ReferenceItems.OfType<CustomerType>().ToList()
                    .OrderBy(o => o.DisplayOrder)
                    .ThenBy(o => o.Name));
        }

        public ActionResult Details(long? id)
        {
            ViewBag.Header = DisplayName;
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            CustomerType custType = (CustomerType)db.ReferenceItems.Find(id);
            if (custType == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View("/Views/ReferenceItems/Details.cshtml", custType);
        }
    }

    // Order Types
    public class OrderTypesController : Controller
    {
        private Context db = new Context();
        private string DisplayName = "Order Type";
        private string DisplayNamePlural = "Order Types";

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Header = DisplayNamePlural;
            return View("~/Views/ReferenceItems/Index.cshtml"
                , db.ReferenceItems.OfType<OrderType>().ToList()
                    .OrderBy(o => o.DisplayOrder)
                    .ThenBy(o => o.Name));
        }

        public ActionResult Details(long? id)
        {
            ViewBag.Header = DisplayName;
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            OrderType orderType = (orderType)db.ReferenceItems.Find(id);
            if (orderType == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View("/Views/ReferenceItems/Details.cshtml", orderType);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you show us your nearly identical controllers?

Comment: Added sampling of the controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, should you have a controller for ReferenceItems? Then you could have a single view to display a ReferenceItem, and have a couple of simple views to switch the type?

I would personally do it in a single controller with multiple views and pass the type as the argument:

```
// Reference Types
public class ReferenceTypesController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult() CustomerIndex()
    {
        return Index<Customer>();
    }

    public ActionResult() OrderIndex()
    {
        return Index<Order>();
    }

    public ActionResult Index<ReferenceType>()
    {
        ViewBag.Header = DisplayNamePlural;
        return View("~/Views/ReferenceItems/Index.cshtml"
            , db.ReferenceItems.OfType<ReferenceType>().ToList()
                .OrderBy(o => o.DisplayOrder)
                .ThenBy(o => o.Name));
    }

}
```

Comment: Would I need to create a custom route map for that? What would it look like? Thanks.

Comment: Well you don't need to no, you could just access it by ReferenceTypes/CustomerIndex or ReferenceTypes/OrderIndex

Comment: It looks like I need to choose between one controller with views for each type or a dedicated controller for each type with one set of views to server them all. Since there will be many different types, I think I'll stick with one set of views and dedicated controllers. Marking this as the answer, though, as it did show me a different way to go about it. Thanks.